# Eagerly caching Mono

Tags: spring, project-reactor

I'm looking to eagerly cache the results of a Reactor Mono. It's scheduled to be updated in cache every 10 minutes, but since the Mono is only evaluated when subscribed to, the task doesn't actually refresh the cache.

Example:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10 * 60 * 1000 + 3000)
fun getMessage(): Mono<String> {
    return Mono.just("Hello")
            .map { it.toUpperCase() }
            .cache(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
}
```

Comment: Is it `Kotlin`?

Comment: Yes, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your `Mono` somewhere, otherwise each invocation of the method (through the `Scheduled` or directly) will return a different instance.

Perhaps as a companion object?

Here is how I would do it naïvely in Java:

```
protected Mono<String> cached;

//for the scheduler to periodically eagerly refresh the cache
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10 * 60 * 1000 + 3000)
void refreshCache() {
    this.cached = Mono.just("Hello")
            .map { it.toUpperCase() }
            .cache(Duration.ofMinutes(10));
    this.cached.subscribe(v -> {}, e -> {}); //swallows errors during refresh
}

//for users
public Mono<String> getMessage() {
    return this.cached;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work. Are there any plans of making this more fluent in the future? For instance adding an extra parameter to the cache call to eagerly cache on invocation?

Comment: no plan to do so, no. if you want to eagerly populate the cache, you'll need to immediately subscribe to it.